# Selenium C# does not want to run due to localhost

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape a site using Selenium and FireFox, when I replicate this into python it works but in C# I get the error OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:53355/' . I don't have FireFox/ geckodriver open and they are both at the latest version.
Here is code:

```
public async Task<string> scrapeURL()
{
    var driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"geckodriver.exe");
    driverService.BrowserCommunicationPort = 26877; 
    var options = new FirefoxOptions();

    using (var driver = new FirefoxDriver(driverService, options)) -- error
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(await driverURL());
        var lastHeight = (long)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.body.scrollHeight;");
        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");

        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        var elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[contains(@class, 'SolidButton')]"));

        foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            var href = element.GetAttribute("href");
            var title = element.GetAttribute("title");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(href) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
            {
                return title + ": " + href;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I should of got my hrefs and titles returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code here, on Windows at least. I can get it to run fine following the steps below in a clean virtual machine using Visual Studio 2022. Obviously you need Firefox installed  as well.

1. Create a C# console app, .NET 8.0, called ConsoleApp1.  Check 'Do not use top-level statements'.
2. Install NuGet package Selenium.WebDriver (Tools/NuGet Package Manager/Manage NuGet Packages for Solution... and Browse for Selenium.WebDriver and install the latest)
3. Copy in the code below to Program.cs, which is a minimum reproducible example of the code provided, I think:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            string result = await new Program().scrapeURL();
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }

        public async Task<string> scrapeURL()
        {
            var driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"geckodriver.exe");
            driverService.BrowserCommunicationPort = 26877;
            var options = new FirefoxOptions();
            options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
            using (var driver = new FirefoxDriver(driverService, options))
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

3. Download the latest geckodriver from [the Mozilla site](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).  I downloaded [geckodriver-v0.34.0-win32.zip](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.34.0/geckodriver-v0.34.0-win32.zip).  Copy the downloaded geckodriver.exe to the bin\Debug\net8.0 subfolder using File Explorer.
4. Run by using menu option Debug/Start Without Debugging.  google.com should appear.

The geckodriver seems to pick a different unused port on every run, so this does look like some sort of install problem rather than a genuine port conflict, by the way.

Note that for some reason the code above can't find Firefox without the additional statement setting the BinaryLocation.  This in spite of the fact that Firefox is installed in the default location.  I don't think this is the problem in the provided code though: it gives a different error.

In short 'it runs on my machine' :-)  In fact it runs on all my machines, and I think there must be something specific to your setup that's causing the issue.

Comment: tysm, it was the geckodriver after all. thanks for taking time out of your day!